# Error init SpringBoot app. I have a SpringBoot app. 2.1.5.RELEASE that uses Kakfa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-kafka

I have a SpringBoot app. 2.1.5.RELEASE that uses Spring for Apache Kafka (Kafka-based messaging solutions), with IntelliJ IDEA
I have created this service:

```
public class KafkaProducerService {

    private static final String TOPIC = "bendiciones";

    private final KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate;

    public KafkaProducerService(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message){
        log.info(String.format("$$ -> Producing message --> %s",message));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC,message);
    }
}
```

but when I start the app. I got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:721)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at com.bendiciones.buenas.noches.Application.main(Application.java:38)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor
```

these are my dependencies in the po, file:

```
       <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>

    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            </dependency>
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

Comment: Errors like this come from mixing jars from different versions of spring, i.e being incomatible. Make sure you are using the spring-boot-starters to get the correct dependencies.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot 2.1.x, which uses Spring 5.1, you are using Spring Kafka 2.3.x which requires Spring 5.2. Incompatible versions. Use 2.2.x instead or upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.x.

Comment: @M.Deinum, please convert to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of errors generally come from mixing jars from different versions of the framework. They should all match or else you will run into these kind of issues.

Looking at your depenendencies you are using Spring Boot 2.1.x which relies on Spring Framework 5.1.x. You also want to use Kafka and for that included Spring Kafka 2.3.3, however this version uses/expects Spring 5.2. Spring 5.1 and 5.2 aren't compatible so you are running into issues.

Remove the `<version>` tag from the Spring Kafka dependency. Spring Boot will automatically manage the dependency for you to a proper compatible version.